# Cookies from within shiro ldap realm code

Tags: grails, cookies, ldap, shiro

I'm using shiro in my grails app for authentication and authorization. Out corporate architecture uses a separate LDAP server for each country we have offices in. Its a lot. I'm trying to set a cookie from with in the shiro realm code that I can check on the next login. I've tried the grails cookie plugin but apparently can't get the injection to work into the realm code.

Has anyone gotten something similar to work, if so any hints?

Answer (score 0):

It helps if I put the injection in the right place, outside the method.